# Should we mark questions as duplicate of closed questions?

Tags: feature-request

I've wondered about this before, but my current example is this question:

[Contracting role versus permanent role? What is the difference?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21729/contracting-role-versus-permanent-role-what-is-the-difference)

which is voted to be closed as a duplicate of:

[Difference between contract and full time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/difference-between-contract-and-full-time)

This is more of a general question though, as I think it's not really constructive to send people who want to help through a string of closed questions. If a question is a duplicate of another question that is closed, in my opinion the duplicate should be closed for the same reason, not just for being a dup.

**Feature request** here is to not list closed questions in the duplicate search results.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186706/can-we-prevent-questions-from-being-closed-as-duplicates-of-closed-questions

Comment: @gnat I also proposed this almost 3 years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87148/closed-questions-shouldnt-be-allowed-to-be-possible-duplicates

Comment: @NickC I love your scientific diagram. From the number and age of requests around this issue, I assume, it's not going to happen, though...

Comment: @CMW I completely agree, if the old duplicate is closed then the new one should as well. I actually thought it was strange that People were "complaining" that I linked to a closed question.

Answer (score 8):

> Full disclosure: I was the close voter who marked the duplicate as stated above

My method is (maybe too) simple: will clicking the link get the person the answer they are looking for? If yes, vote to close as a dupe. If no, consider leaving it open and answering it better than the information in those other closed questions. If you do it well enough, then vote to close those other questions as dupes of this new one if it is far superior.

Since the dupe I pointed to actually addresses the difference only between full-time and contractor in the answer, I figured that was the better of the two. The third one tosses in a third category of employee and is a lot longer, but likely won't do a better job answering the asked question. And anyway, if the first dupe doesn't have enough, that person can always click through to the second dupe and decide themselves.

Comment: I absoultely get and agree with the idea of pointing them to another question that's got helpful answers already. I just think it's akin to posting link-only answers. Closed questions are way more likely to be deleted completely, leaving the question closed with a missing dup (and probably still off-topic because the dup used to be off-topic, too). It might be a better approach to close for another reason, if actually off-topic/too broad/opinion-based, and link to that other question in a comment.

Comment: @CMW, Well, that question has been around for almost 2 years without deletion yet, so I don't see that as that big of a risk. It is upvoted, [so the system won't auto-delete it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/). Of course, you can always create a tremendous answer to the current question, and flag the old question to be a dupe of the current, or reopen the previous question, or find a different creative way to handle it if you're worried about deletion.

Comment: I'm also not criticising this particular example, it just reminded me of several situation, where I was thinking about this

Comment: I also think there is something that prevents questions that are linked to from being deleted. But I could be mistaken on that, as I can not find the SOMeta post I would swear I read it in.

Comment: @Chad questions that are linked to are deleted just the same as these that aren't (at Programmers we had recently cleaned up quite a bunch of questions that had deleted ones ion dupe notices)

Answer (score 3):

If the questions are duplicates, it shouldn't matter if the target is closed.  The alternative would be to close the new question for the same reason, which is less friendly than linking them together.  If the new question *isn't* off-topic or too broad or whatever led to the other being closed, then it's not a duplicate.

Remember that being put on hold or closed -- including being marked as a duplicate -- needn't be permanent.  The status of the question should reflect the current content.  If you can edit a closed or on-hold question to address the issue, please do so and vote to reopen.  We want good, open questions and their answers; what we don't want is to artificially keep a question open that should have been put on hold.  That just leads to a jumble of answers to, possibly, the wrong question.